# Android: Possible to write into /etc folder?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to know whether it is possible to write data in /etc folder (or any other folder besides data)? If yes, how to do that?

And if not possible, any way to store a permanent data? For scenario example, an app is uninstalled (or clear data), but a specific file will still remain.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure about /etc folder, but the stuff saved in /data folder is managed by android automatically itself. So when you uninstall an app, anything related to it is also removed from data folder.

However, to store a file permanently besides Data folder on your SdCard, see the code below:

```
public static boolean saveOnFile(String msg){
        boolean saved = false;

        String filename = "yourFileName.extension";

        try{
            if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
                File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/YourFolderOnSdCard/");

                //create root folders if they do not exist
                if(!root.exists()){
                    root.mkdirs();
                }

                //now lets save file in our directory structure
                File file = new File(root, filename);

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                fw.append(msg);
                fw.flush();
                fw.close();

                saved = true;
            }
            else
                Log.e("Save", "Mounted media is not available or is write-protected");
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Log.e("Save", e.toString()); }

        return saved;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Although it's not reliable enough, but it looks like using external storage is the only way to help me track my app installation. hmm.

Answer (score 0):

This [Data Storage guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) could be useful.

Comment: Thanks...i've reviewed it, it seems the only way to do it is by using external storage..